# Scalar extension of group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, group-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring, let $G$ be a group and let $R[G]$ its group $R$-algebra.

- It is true that $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\simeq R[G]$?
- If not, there are conditions on $R$ and $G$ which ensure this?

Thank you and sorry if the question is too obvious.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the fact that tensoring preserves arbitrary direct sums.

Comment: Thank you very much.